# ¿Cómo ir a otros archivos (proyectos) en React sin usar React Router?

Tags: reactjs

Estoy desarrollando mi Portfolio con React, el problema radica a la hora de poner mis enlaces a mis proyectos, no se como hacerlo sin usar React Router, por lo que entiendo este ultimo es para navegar dentro de una misma app, mi caso seria para navegar hacia otra página con mis proyectos.

Comment: Por favor agrega el código de lo que has intentado. Te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Dentro del proyecto podrías desplazarte entre las diferentes rutas utilizando el componente `<Link>` u otros recursos que ofrece React-Router.

---

Si lo que deseas es linkear a un proyecto externo puedes simplemente usar una etiqueta `<a>`.

**Ejemplo Local:**
App1: localhost:5100
App2: localhost:5200

Para acceder desde App1 a App2 podrías usar algo así:

```
<a href="http://localhost:5200">Ir a App2</a>
```

Por supuesto esto haría que se recargue la página con el nuevo proyecto.

**Ejemplo Deployado:**
App1: app1.com
App2: app2.com

Para acceder desde App1 a App2 podrías usar algo así:

```
<a href="https://www.app2.com">Ir a App2</a>
```

De igual manera haría que se recargue la página con el nuevo proyecto.